# Downloading iOS music from iTunes onto iPad without being erased

Tags: ios, itunes, ipad, music

My dad bought me ed Sheeran new album on his iTunes so now we want to get it on my iPad. I have my own Apple ID account but I haven't bought any music.

How can I download the album my Dad bought to my iPad without deleting anything on it?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can download it on your computer, then sync with iTunes your music by activating `Manually manage music and videos` on your device's options.

That will allow you to just drag and drop music to your device without deleting anything on it.

Source: [Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201593)

Comment: Will this work even if OP's dad purchased the music on their iTunes account?  I haven't tried this so I don't know if you can purchase music and then give the song to someone else who uses a different Apple ID.

Comment: So doing this won't erase any data on my iPad even though it's a different device and iTunes apples id?